# Why doesn't my python program run forever? "Unexpectedly quit"

Tags: python

I am doing a math problem that requires me to multiply numbers and check to see if they are palindromes.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000)
import time

def values():
    x=999
    y=999
    product=0
    generator(x,y,product)

def generator(x,y,product):
    while x >= 900:
        product=x*y
        strp=str(product)
        check=strp[::-1]
        print (check)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if strp==check:
            print ("done")
        x=x-1
    else:
        y=y-1
        generator(x,y,product)

values()
```

I am using Mac, and it goes through the loop a couple of times but then displays a "Pytho quit unexpectedly" error.

Comment: Why use recursion for this? And why the `time.sleep()` call?

Comment: I don't see another way to do it? The time.sleep() call wasn't the problem, it is just something I tried to see if it changed the place where the program stops running.

Comment: Also, you never `return` anything.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? The fact that you are manually setting the recursion limit is a huge red flag. What is your input going to be, what is the out put you want and what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Your program is crashing because your recursion loop doesn't stop. When `x` reaches the value of `900` the `generate` function always calls the `else` branch of its code. You reed to add a condition for the loop to stop. Otherwise it fills up the memory, making the program crash because recursion loops have a limit on how many times you call them.

Comment: But I don't want the loop to stop? Why can't it just keep going?

Comment: Your program crashes because everytime you do a recursion call, the function is added to the stack (in memory), if you never stop then if just fills up the memory, making the program crash because you can't do infinite recursion calls. This is the issue with your code as I see it. I don't really see what you're trying to do with your code, but you should probably redefine exactly what you want to accomplish, and maybe ask a new question if you're stuck.

Comment: I can manually quit it when i'm happy with it. It doesn't seem like this would be a impossibility. Is there some "memory leak" type phenomena? f

Comment: I suppose "you keep adding to memory forever, on purpose" is a sort of memory leak, yes. You cannot get away with doing that unless you have infinite memory.

Comment: Is there any simple way where I could keep the loop going without adding to the stack?

Comment: You could rewrite it using a `while` loop.

Comment: Yeah that works, thanks a lot. It is really nice that you guys take the time to help out a beginner like me.

Answer (score 0):

As per the answer above, your recursion never stops because once x = 900 it always recurses by calling the else code.

I suggest the following solutions:
a) If you're interested in keeping y at 999 until x is 900 and then decrease y until it's 900 you should add the following to your else (i.e. do 999x999, 999x998... 999x900 ... 998x900 ... 900 x 900):

```
else:
    if y >= 900:
       generator(x,y,product)
       y=y-1
```

b)If you want to recurse on both of them (i.e. decrease them in parallel):

```
def generator(x,y,product):
    if x >= 900 and y >=900:
        product=x*y
        strp=str(product)
        check=strp[::-1]
        print (check)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if strp==check:
            print ("done")
        x=x-1
        y=y-1
        generator(x, y, product)
```

Personally I would recommend the second solution as it's neater.

Please note that when recursing on both of them you don't need to have while loops, an if check is enough.